# Why do custom read op only works on test_session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wrote an custom kernel op in tensorflow for reading csv format data.

It works fine in the TestCase with the `sess` object return by `test_session()` function.

When I turn to normal codes, the reader op returns the same result every time. Then I put some debug printing at the beginning of the `MyOp:Compute` function. It seems like after the first run, the `sess.run(myop)` never calls the `MyOp:Compute` function at all.

Then I return to my test cases, if I replace the session object with an `tf.Session()` instead of `self.test_session()`, it failed the same way.

Anyone has any idea about this?

to share more details, here's my mini demo codes: 
 https://github.com/littleDing/mini_csv_reader

in the test case:

```
def testSimple(self):
  input_data_schema, feas, batch_size = self.get_simple_format()
  iter_op = ops.csv_iter('./sample_data.txt', input_data_schema, feas, batch_size=batch_size, label='label2')
  with self.test_session() as sess:
    label,sign = sess.run(iter_op)
    print label

    self.assertAllEqual(label.shape, [batch_size])
    self.assertAllEqual(sign.shape, [batch_size, len(feas)])
    self.assertAllEqual(sum(label), 2)
    self.assertAllEqual(sign[0,:], [7,0,4,1,1,1,5,9,8])

    label,sign = sess.run(iter_op)
    self.assertAllEqual(label.shape, [batch_size])
    self.assertAllEqual(sign.shape, [batch_size, len(feas)])
    self.assertAllEqual(sum(label), 1)
    self.assertAllEqual(sign[0,:], [9,9,3,1,1,1,5,4,8])
```

for normal call:

```
def testing_tf():
    path = './sample_data.txt'
    input_data_schema, feas, batch_size = get_simple_format()
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        n_data_op = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
        iter_op = ops.csv_iter(path, input_data_schema, feas, batch_size=batch_size, label='label2') 
        init_op = [tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer() ]

    with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      n_data = 0
      for batch_idx in range(3):
        print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>> before run batch', batch_idx
        ## it should be some debug printing here, but nothing come out when batch_idx>0
        label,sign = sess.run(iter_op)
        print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>> after run batch', batch_idx
        ## the content of sign remain the same every time
        print sign
        if len(label) == 0:
          break
```

Comment: Can you share specific code to understand more clear

Comment: Please try to share a minimal working example of the problem. Without code that illustrates your problem, we are unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: @Engineero  I've update the minimal working codes, would you like to have a check?

Comment: @SalihKaragoz I've update the minimal working codes, would you like to have a check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A look at the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9b9cbbe2a69b7fcec72d82f271cb90839c3035b7/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L706) of `tf.test.TestCase.test_session()` provides a few clues, because it configures the session somewhat differently than a straight call to `tf.Session`. In particular, `test_session()` [disables](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9b9cbbe2a69b7fcec72d82f271cb90839c3035b7/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L773) the **constant folding** optimization. By default, TensorFlow will convert **stateless** parts of your graph into `tf.constant()` nodes, because they will produce the same result each time you run them.

In the registration of your `"CsvIter"` op, there is on `SetIsStateful()` annotation, so TensorFlow will treat it as **stateless**, and hence subject to constant folding. However, its implementation is very stateful: in general any op that you would expect to produce different results with the same input tensors, or any op that stores mutable state in member variables, should be marked stateful.

The solution is a one-line change to the `REGISTER_OP` for `"CsvIter"`:

```
REGISTER_OP("CsvIter")
    .Input("data_file: string")
    .Output("labels: float32")
    .Output("signs: int64")
    .Attr("input_schema: list(string)")
    .Attr("feas: list(string)")
    .Attr("label: string = 'label' ")
    .Attr("batch_size: int = 10000")
    .SetIsStateful();  // Add this line.
```